# How many MAPPERS used in MapReduce job result?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I run my MapReduce job on the cluster. The output I get is:

```
 Map-Reduce Framework
            CPU time spent (ms)=1252250
            Combine input records=0
            Combine output records=0
            Failed Shuffles=0
            GC time elapsed (ms)=501
            Input split bytes=468
            Map input records=9544259
            Map output bytes=715844289
            Map output materialized bytes=49747243
            Map output records=75764209
            Merged Map outputs=8
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=3090530304
            Reduce input groups=678956
            Reduce input records=75764209
            Reduce output records=111536
            Reduce shuffle bytes=49747243
            Shuffled Maps =8
            Spilled Records=220019817
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=3500670976
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=16934440960
```

**I want to answer:  how many mappers are used by Hadoop to process the data using the result of the job, above ^^^**

*Am I correct in thinking that the mapper output records is the number of mappers used to process the data?*

Comment: The mapper output records is NOT the number of mappers.  You need Job level counters, they are maintained by the jobtracker `TOTAL_LAUNCHED_MAPS` - is a number of mappers. For example JobCounter.TOTAL_LAUNCHED_MAPS:1342

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my misconception. Job Counters
                Data-local map tasks=4
                Launched map tasks=4        So I think that since there were 4 launched map tasks, then there were 4 mappers used to process the data.I am looking at the counters under "Job Counters" . I don't see the word TOTAL, however there are "launched map tasks =4".

Comment: Data-local map tasks=4
                Launched map tasks=4
                Launched reduce tasks=3
Just to confirm: that the launched map tasks under job counters is the number of mappers used to process data. And there were 3 reducers to reduce/process data. Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, you are right now